# Split string on double / triple line breaks

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to convert a JavaScript to PowerShell that insert "seperator line" between double / triple line breaks.

**JavaScript**

```js
html = html.replace(/\:\s*\n\s*/g, ":\n" ); //sentences ending with : is not the end of a paragraph, but the start of something new 
html = html.replace(/\n\s*\n\s*\n/g, replaceChar ); 
html = html.replace(/\n\s*\n\s*/g, replaceChar );
```

Instead of inserting a seperator line (`replaceChar`) I want to split it into an array.

I've tried this but can't manage what I'm doing wrong.

**PowerShell**

```bsh
$html = $html -replace "/\:\s*\n\s*/g", ":\n"
$html = $html -split "/\n\s*\n\s*\n/g" -split "/\n\s*\n\s*/g"
```

ex:

```bsh
$html = "Ipusm lorem – Outsourcing


ipsum lorem lorem ipsum. ipsum. lorem:

test testads fsadf dsa fsa


            asdf dsa fdsa fdsa fsa .a fdsa dsa f."
```

to be

```bsh
$html[0] = "Ipusm lorem – Outsourcing"
$html[1] = "ipsum lorem lorem ipsum. ipsum. lorem:
test testads fsadf dsa fsa"
$html[2] = "asdf dsa fdsa fdsa fsa .a fdsa dsa f."
```

Comment: Can you show some sample text and expected results from your query just to be clear?

Comment: PowerShell does not use JavaScript syntax for Regex.

Comment: @PetSerAl Where do I use JavaScript syntax? Thought -replace and -split took regex input.. ??

Comment: `/` and `g` in your Regex match literal characters. It is not delimiter and option as in JavaScript.

Comment: @PetSerAl What's the way around this "problem" ?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the linebreak after the colon?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I was hoping to preserve it, but that's not important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If preserving the line break after the colon is not required, I'd mangle consecutive whitespace after colons to a single space, split the result at newlines, then remove blank lines:

```
$html -replace ':\s*', ': ' -split '\n' | Where-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

If you want the remaining lines trimmed as well modify the above like this:

```
$html -replace ':\s*', ': ' -split '\n' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } |
    Where-Object { $_ }
```

Depending on the input and your requirements you might be able to re-add the line break after colons like this:

```
$html -replace ':\s*', ': ' -split '\n' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() -replace ':', ":`n" } |
    Where-Object { $_ }
```

Another option would be to mangle a newline and subsequent whitespace after a colon into a single newline and then split the string at 2+ newlines:

```
$html -replace ':\n\s*', ":`n" -split '\n{2,}' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } |
    Where-Object { $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
$html = "Ipusm lorem – Outsourcing`r`n`r`n`r`nipsum lorem lorem ipsum. ipsum. lorem:`r`n`r`ntest testads fsadf dsa fsa`r`n`r`n`r`n `r`n          asdf dsa fdsa fdsa fsa .a fdsa dsa f."
$chunks = $html -split "\r?\n(?:\p{Zs}*\r?\n){2,}\p{Zs}*"
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX9qY1/4)

The regex matches:

- `\r?\n` - a linbreak (optional CR followed with LF)
- `(?:\p{Zs}*\r?\n){2,}` - two or more sequences of:

  - `\p{Zs}*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace symbols
  - `\r?\n` - optional CR followed with LF
- `\p{Zs}*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace symbols

See the output:

[image]

Comment: You could just run `function prompt{'PS> '}` to hide your working directory.